# GAE datastore cache keys vs filter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

Lets say you have an Entity like this.

```
postid=db.StringProperty()
comment=db.StringProperty()
```

for storing comments on a certain post identified by post id.
The comments can hit billions of records. Now if you want to 
get all comments belonging to a certain post you can do,

```
query=Comment.all()
query.filter('postid = ','id').
```

Or instead of doing that you can define post like

```
class Post(db.Model)
    commentids=db.StringListProperty()#store list of comment ids
```

This way you can directly get the comment by doing

```
comment=Comment.get_by_key_name('commentkey')
```

In the long run (when comments hit millions or even billions mark) which one
is more efficient. In other words which one is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're planning to have billions of comments consider also using the newest [NDB API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/), which, among other things, supports automatic caching.

Instead of filtering them by `postid` you should probably use a parent for your `Comment` entity. Here is an example (using DB, but it's very similar using NDB):

If you have model like this one:

```
class Post(db.Model):
  desc = db.StringProperty()

class Comment(db.Model):
  desc = db.TextProperty()
```

You can create posts and comments like:

```
post_db = Post(desc='Hello World')
post_db.put()

comment_db = Comment(parent=post_db, desc='Nice post')
comment_db.put()
```

And finally if you want to get all the comments from a particular `post_db` entity:

```
comment_dbs = Comment.all().ancestor(post_db)
```

Comment: By doing this though, in the HR datastore you limit yourself to about 1-2 write per entity group per second. If you expect a high frequency of commenting on each post, then you will have to mitigate this (try using pull queues or a push queue with a 2/s execution rate) or explicitly catching contention exceptions and retrying the post later.

Comment: Entity groups are to be used when you need transactons, not as a parent-child relationship.

Comment: @PeterKnego I think there are other examples that even if you don't need transactions you can use ancestors. For example if you have User and Setting entities, you could use the same `key_name` for different kind of settings to get the advantage of: `Setting.get_or_insert(background_color, parent=user_db, value='#ff0000')` without including something ugly and unique in the key_name :)

Comment: @PeterKnego or it should be avoided in general if you're not using transactions?

Comment: Awesome thanks! So when you do 

    Comment.all().ancestor(post_db)

a list of records is being fetched like, records=SomeMap[post_db]? If so then it should be quite fast and will solve my headache!

Comment: The ancestor solution looks fine, the postid query should work too.  The list of commentids in the Post doesn't scale well, you end up with rewriting the Post each time a comment is added.

Answer (score 0):

Entities are limited to 1MB in size. Also, entity can have max 5000 index entries, so if your `commentids` is indexed then the max size would be 5000 entries.

So option two would not be a good fit for millions of comments (I've never seen a site with a million of comments per post, but Reddit does get over 5k for popular posts.

Also, you'd probably need a way to list comments in a progressive way (pagging, progressive scrolling). In this case option one via query would be better as you could list comments progressivelly via cursors and also you could sort properties via different criteria ( time, votes, etc..).

Comment: Thanks, the problem for me is not the number of comments per post. I am worried about the speed of execution when you filter from Comment.all() when number of entities under Comment hits a large number. I am very much aware of 5k limit and I dont think I will ever hit that limit for a single post.